# isNil can't be used on literals

Tags: null, nim-lang

```
echo 0.isNil
```

> type mismatch: got < int literal(0)>
>   but expected one of: 
>   proc isNil[T: proc](x: T): bool
>   proc isNil[T](x: ptr T): bool
>   proc isNil(x: cstring): bool
>   proc isNil(x: pointer): bool
>   proc isNil(x: string): bool
>   proc isNil[T](x: seq[T]): bool
>   proc isNil[T](x: ref T): bool

How are we supposed to write generic code when we can't have expressions like `0.isNil` ?

Comment: There's never any need for that expression in generic or any other code. `0` is no more equal to `nil` than `1` is.

Comment: @JimBalter come on, a little bit of imagination. If I asked that, it's that I had a use case. `0` is not equal to `nil`, it's not what I said. I meant: `0.isNil` is false, and `1.isNil` is false too (because a literal exists). Duck typing can't be used if generic trait function like that are not universal.

Comment: I have more than enough imagination. The argument is completely bogus, and the question is poorly written pure hyperbole with no supporting evidence. As noted by the comment by uran, "Just like isEven and isOdd is defined for integers, why don't you complain that isEven is not defined for Files, because Files are not even, neither they are odd, right?" That's my final response.

Comment: @JimBalter the philosophy for this motivation is in this article https://motsd1inge.wordpress.com/category/software/engineering/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `isNil` on types that can't be `nil`, that just doesn't make sense. When going generic (let's say you're implementing `MyContainer[T]`) you just introduce a new notion of emptiness (whatever that means to you) and use it in your generic code.

```
proc isEmptyElement[T](v: T): bool {.inline.} =
  when compiles(isNil(v)):
    isNil(v)
  elif T is SomeNumber:
    v == 0
  else:
    # Whatever else you mean by emptiness. Let's say is v the default value of T
    var d: T # Default value
    v == d

proc myContainerAdd[T](c: MyContainer[T], v: T) =
  if not v.isEmptyElement():
    # proceed
```

Note `isEmptyElement` can be simplified, it has more branches than actually needed just to demonstrate different approaches.

Comment: special cases are not special enough to break the rules & http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2013/11/unconditional-programming.html

Comment: You reimplemented `isNil` (by convenience wrapping it). That's a good proof that `isNil` is incomplete. And `valuetype.isNil` should return `false` it's easy to define and it makes perfect sense. What you introduce here is a notion covered by `Option[T]` https://nim-lang.org/docs/options.html which does not solve generic programming.

Comment: You can look at it from a different perspective. `isNil` is just a function defined for types that can be `nil`. You can define your own for your own type. Just like `isEven` and `isOdd` is defined for integers, why don't you complain that `isEven` is not defined for `File`s, because `File`s are not even, neither they are odd, right? If your generic algorithm needs to know whether a value (is nillable and is nil) that's a problem specific to just your algorithm, and you can solve it locally, with no extra abstractions leaking.

Answer (score 2):

[Implement all the types](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/all-the-things)!

```
proc isNil(x: int): string = "meme"

echo 0.isNil
```

Comment: lol so basically we need to patch the language because it is incomplete. great

Comment: what do I do with float, double, literals, byte, char ..? what we want is not `int` but `value type` concept or something

Comment: @v.oddou you could write `proc isNil[T](x: T)` but if it is not done, maybe I would ask the Nim developers if there is a good reason for, and if not, make a pull request.

Comment: yes the generic `T` sounds like the missing overload. now what needs to be proven, is that a better matching generic is always going to be selected for overload resolution. (ref T..)